# How would I apply multiprocessing to this Python3 script?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have been working on this code with the intention of using it to purchase things online. As you can see, the code is supposed to open a page and input a proxy, then wait until the product drops and purchase it. I have been having a lot of trouble finding a way to integrate a way to run this code multiple times at once so that I can checkout a lot of times when the product drops. I have read countless hours about multiprocessing, but I can’t seem to figure out how to apply it to my code. Could anybody please help me by fixing my code? Preemptive thank you for your time :)

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import pyautogui
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests
from itertools import cycle
import traceback
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
from datetime import datetime, time
from time import sleep

hostname = "hostname"
port = "378798"
proxy_username = "kajflnsdlkfjds"
proxy_password = "kjdnfakljdsn"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(hostname + ":" + port))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

def enter_proxy_auth(proxy_username, proxy_password):
    t.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.typewrite(proxy_username)
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    pyautogui.typewrite(proxy_password)
    pyautogui.press('enter')


def open_a_page(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)


Thread(target=open_a_page, args=(driver, "http://www.google.com/")).start()
Thread(target=enter_proxy_auth, args=(proxy_username, proxy_password)).start()

def act(x):
    return x+10

def wait_start(runTime, action):
    startTime = time(*(map(int, runTime.split(':'))))
    while startTime > datetime.today().time(): # you can add here any additional variable to break loop if necessary
        sleep(1)# you can change 1 sec interval to any other
    return action
wait_start('21:51', lambda: act(100))
driver.get('https://url')

product = '//*[@id=""]/button/span'

price = '//*[@id=""]'

check_out_now = '//*[@id=""]/div/div[1]/button'

name = '//*[@id=""]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/label/input'

street = '//*[@id=""]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/div[1]/label/input'

town = '//*[@id=""]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/div[3]/label/input'

state_first = '//*[@id=""]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/div[4]/label/select/option[37]'

zipcode = '//*[@id=""]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/div[5]/label/input'

continue_to_payment = '//*[@id=""]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/button'

proceed_to_paypal = '//*[@id=""]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/button'

pay_with_debit = '//*[@id=""]'

card_number = '//*[@id=""]'

exp_info = '//*[@id=""]'

cvv = '//*[@id=""]'

first_name = '//*[@id=""]'

last_name = '//*[@id=""]'

address = '//*[@id=""]'

city = '//*[@id=""]'

state = '//*[@id=""]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/span/span/span'

zip_code = '//*[@id=""]'

phone = '//*[@id=""]'

email = '//*[@id=""]'

pay_now = '//*[@id=""]'



driver.implicitly_wait(30)
  #driver.find_element_by_xpath(pay_now).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'')]").click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath(price).send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(check_out_now).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(name).send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(street).send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(town).send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(zipcode).send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(state_first).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(continue_to_payment).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(proceed_to_paypal).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(pay_with_debit).click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(exp_info).send_keys("")
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath(card_number)
for character in "":
    el.send_keys(character)
    t.sleep(0.0075)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(cvv).send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(phone).send_keys("")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(email).send_keys("johndoe@gmai.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(pay_now).click()
```

Comment: If you execute two instances of this are 2 windows opened and handled as expected?

Comment: Yes they are, but the issue I am having is having them all run concurrently.

Comment: The first thing you have to do is to put the workload you want to run in parallel in a function and make it return the desired work result. Then you can use the `multiprocessing` module to spawn multiple processes.

Comment: Are you sure you want multi-threading? It opens its own can of worms. Can't you get away with just a loop if you want to repeat an action?

Comment: Yes, it needs to use multi-threading, Robert, because the code needs to get run multiple times at a single time in order to make the purchases that I am trying to make.

Comment: thank you, Klaus, I will try implementing your suggestion.

Comment: multiprocessing != multithreading

Comment: I am aware of this, Juanpa, thank you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `multiprocessing.dummy` is multithreading ;)